# How to hide a div element by using show(), hide() & off()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I came across `off()` function, which is used to turn off some functionality, so I tried to show & hide an element using this :

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="showOrHide();">=</button>
        <div class="container-fluid" id="dDown">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 box-style"><a href="#">Home</a></div>
                <div class="col-md-3 box-style"><a href="#">About us</a></div>
                <div class="col-md-3 box-style"><a href="#">Contact</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            function showOrHide()
            {   
                $("#dDown").hide();
                $("#dDown").click(function(){
                    $("#dDown").show();
                    $("#dDown").off("click");
                });
            }
            $(document).ready(function(){showOrHide();});
        </script>
```

This code isn't showing the element.

Comment: Can you detail what you're *trying* to do (in words, not code).   Should the "=" button show *and* hide if it's clicked multiple times?  What should happen if you click on "#dDown"?  What about a second time?

Comment: @freedomn-m So, here's what I want to do : 1. On loading, the div element with id "dDown" will be hidden. 2. Upon clicking the button, the <div> element with id "dDown" will be shown & 3. Upon clicking the button again, the <div> element with id "dDown" will hide again.

Comment: Right, so no need for `$("#dDown").click` or `.off` as you're not interesting in clicking #dDown - a simple toggle from the button (edit: as per accepted answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$("#dDown").toggle();` to solve this

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="showOrHide();">=</button>
        <div class="container-fluid" id="dDown">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 box-style"><a href="#">Home</a></div>
                <div class="col-md-3 box-style"><a href="#">About us</a></div>
                <div class="col-md-3 box-style"><a href="#">Contact</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            function showOrHide()
            {   
                $("#dDown").toggle();
                
            }
            $(document).ready(function(){showOrHide();});
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
function showOrHide()
{   
    if($("#dDown").is(":visible")){
        $("#dDown").hide();
    }
    else{
        $("#dDown").show();
        $("#dDown").off("click");
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at what you've written... if #d is visible, show it - if it's not visible, hide it... ?